# Can str_shuffle return a non-shuffled result?

Tags: php, passwords

Today I stumble upon a code I wrote about 10 months ago:

```
$password = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'), 0, 8);
```

I believe I chose this code because it's pretty simple and doesn't require any additional maintenance.

The need to generate a password is because the waiter fills up a quick sign up form on behalf of the customer and we just send the password to said customer.

Now, my question circles around the **possibility** of generating a "12345678" password. I understand the debate between **possibility** and **probability** in this case, but still, picture yourself being signed up for a program and you receive such a lazzy password, wouldn't you question their security?

Comment: Yes, it's highly-improbable but not impossible

Comment: Can't you have a simple database or list containing "*lazy passwords*", and shuffle again if the generated password is a lazy one?.

Comment: @MatiCicero, that's what I'm thinking, but before jumping into that, I decided to make sure that that was necessary. Like I said, I chose this code because it's pretty simple, if I'm going to make it more complex, I have to evaluate the best course of action here.

Comment: it's as possible as a string of abcdefgh .

 I also question any website that gives data in GET or email requests which looks like MD5 hashes...

My point being that just because it's a simple logical string doesn't in isolation state that the security is "questionable". Google Website Authentication codes on their Business (local buisness map) pages are a 6 digit number, is that "lazy" as there are only 1 million possibilities. . . .

Comment: You know, that the generated password is sort of insecure? Only 36 possible chars and no char has the possibility to created twice - that are only 826.517.260.800 possible passwords

Comment: 800 billions looks good enough for me. It's a temporarily password that the software requests a change on the first access. Frankly, I bet tons of people end up putting passwords more insecure than the ones I generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though highly unlikely, it's not impossible

A simple wrapper like

```
$characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
do {
    $password = substr(str_shuffle($characters), 0, 8);
} while (strpos($characters, $password) !== false);
```

will ensure that the generated password isn't a sequence that actually appears in order in the character string

Comment: Oh, you're freakin' good. That's pretty genius and helps me keep the code simple. Thank you.